# azure storage table query all entities in table performance improvement

Tags: python, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-account

In my Azure Storage Account I have a table with over 4 million entities I build this table from a csv file with a size of 978.4 MB. If I read the csv file with Pandas in Python it takes about 1 minute to finish, but if I read the table in my Azure Storage Account with Python it takes hours to get all the data. I know if you query your data based on the PartitionKey and RowKey it will be a lot faster, because those fields are indexed, but is there also something I can do if I just want to collect all the data in a table?

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from azure.cosmosdb.table.tableservice import TableService


def load_sparse_data(self) -> DataFrame:

        sparse_entities = self.table_service.query_entities(self.ats.SPARSE_TABLE)
        sparse_df= pd.DataFrame(list(sparse_entities))

        sparse_df.drop(['PartitionKey', 'RowKey', 'Timestamp', 'etag'], inplace=True, axis=1)

        return sparse_df
```

What do I have to do to speed up collecting all my data from my Azure Storage Account?